# Generate product page with PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm a beginner so this may ba a stupid one.
I'm creating simple platform, which uses a database to manage my post stamps collection. I've managed to set up a database and gather new stamps from user. Now I want to create kind of "product page", which will use data from mySQL. You will be able to enter this page through a dynamically generated table, which will contain all stamps in the database.

The code,which generates a simple table is here:

```
        //connect to database
    $db = mysqli_connect(database login data);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Jest problem z podłączeniem się do bazy danych. Skontaktuj się z administratorem.";
        die();
    }
    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM stamps");
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include "navbar.php" ?>
    <h1>Przeglądaj swoją kolekcję.</h1>
    <?php
    echo "<p><b>View All</b>";

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Nazwa</th> <th>Kraj</th> <th>Wartość nominalna</th> <th>Wartość rynkowa</th> <th>Klaser</th> <th>More info</th> <th>Edytuj</th> <th>Usuń</th></tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                            echo '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row->name . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row->country . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row->price . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row->estimated . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row->album . '</td>';
                            echo "<td><a href=\"stamp.php\">More info.</a></td>";
                            echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row->id . '">Edit</a></td>';
                            echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row->id . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                // close table>
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Now, I'd like to post database values to another page, after clicking "More info" and just view it something like that:

```
<body>
    <?php include "navbar.php" ?>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
        <h1>Znaczek z XIX wieku</h1> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h3>Informacje:</h3> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h5>Numer katalogowy:</h5> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h5>Rok wydania:</h5> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h5>Kraj:</h5> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h5>Wartość nominalna:</h5> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h5>Wartość rynkowa:</h5> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h5>Klaser:</h5> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h3>Opis:</h3> <!-- database data goes here -->
        <h5><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, aliquam, tenetur voluptatibus veritatis numquam expedita nesciunt quos repudiandae similique atque provident ipsam dolorem recusandae id possimus minus ea eum cupiditate!</div>
        <div>Sint, debitis, saepe repellendus commodi recusandae error architecto voluptates soluta ipsa facere perferendis aspernatur quo atque fugiat consequatur! Assumenda necessitatibus dolorem esse distinctio incidunt pariatur praesentium veniam voluptate quae quaerat!</div>></h5>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Edytuj</a></p>
    </div>
    <?php include "footer.php" ?>
</body>
```

The question is: what is the best way to do it ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: sorry, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Add the stamp id to your `More Info` link -> `stamp.php?id=". $row->id ."...`. Then on the stamp page get the id -> `$_GET['id']`  to query your database

Comment: oh, that works pretty sweet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generating page dynamically you can use `$_GET['id']` for getting the id of the table, from where you are gonna fetch the data. Now put a get query after the link you wanna use,

It should look like this
`Index.php?id=2`
It is gonna fetch all the data from the second row.

But if you are like making a admin board or anything that is gonna modify the database do not use this, use secure login with user password verification,

Be sure to sanitize the `id` as this is going to used for getting the data in the database.